# running python files from ipython and passing an object in as the argument

Tags: python, debugging, pandas, ipython

**The overall goal**

I am trying to debug functions that I have written to analyze large data files. It takes too long to read the files into pandas dataframes for each debugging run. And so I am running an ipython console where I want to read the data in, then debug my functions. If I end the debugging session then I will still have the data read into dataframes in the ipython console. Jupyter notebook would be preferable, however it has no debugging functionality.

**The question**

How do I run the debugger on a python file from within a ipython console and then pass a python object into the file as an argument?

Comment: The `Ipython` `%run` magic has a `debug` option.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [IPython.embed()](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/reference.html) where you're currently using `code.InteractiveConsole(globals()).interact('')`.

Make sure you're importing IPython before you do that, though:

```
import IPython
# lots of code
# even more code
IPython.embed()
```

---

You can also save some variables in IPython, so you don't have to run them again.

`%storemagic` stores variables and macros on IPython's database. 
To automatically restore stored variables at startup add this to `ipython_config.py`:

```
c.StoreMagic.autorestore = True
```

Example:

```
In [1]: l = ['hello',10,'world']
In [2]: %store l
In [3]: exit

(IPython session is closed and started again...)

ville@badger:~$ ipython
In [1]: l
Out[1]: ['hello', 10, 'world']
```

Note:

It should be noted that if you change the value of a variable, you need to %store it again if you want to persist the new value.

Note also that the variables will need to be pickleable; most basic python types can be safely %store’d.